# How do i interpret the transformed results from scikit learn's LDA method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using Scikit-Learn's LatentDirichletAllocation model. X is a matrix of 100 documents with 5000 features (100 x 5000). I've run the following code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics = 5)
X_new = lda.fit_transform(X)
```

X_new is now a 100 X 5 matrix, which should be the topic distribution of each document. However, I'm not sure how to interpret the actual values. Each array doesn't sum to 100, so its not a distribution per se. For example, the array for the first two documents are:

```
[66404.6, 0.2, 2004.7, 0.2, 0.2]
[0.2,47.3,0.2,14.0,02]
```

How do I interpret/normalise these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question suits more here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com

But, since you asked it here, each cell is "how much" this document suits one of the n topics (in your case, 5). 
It is not normalized, because each document is being measured separately against each topic (so, in theory all the topics can get a score of 0). If you want to normalize it you of course can, just normalize each line in l1 - and that will show you the distribution of the document against all the topics.

Comment: i.e. its ok to normalise by taking the value of each cell divided by the sum of the row?

Comment: Yes. but this will give you the distribution per 1 document, and you will not be able to compare documents (for example, after normalization, the 2 vectors: [1,2,3,4,5] and [100,200,300,400,500] will be the same - while the second document is 100 times more related to each subject).